# How to fix the type error when using the apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to use the apply function on a column from a table. Here is the sample data and the code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'text':["I love a dog", "He is smart", "I hate this"]})

def edit(input_text):
    output = input_text[:4]
    return output


df['text'].apply(lambda x: edit(x))
```

I thought it was going to apply the edit function on each row in that column, but it gives me the type error.

Comment: The code works for me

Comment: Can you please add the error too in the post?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, please show details error

Comment: The code is working fine for me

Comment: I think you are using `df_train` for the `apply` function. I suppose you should be using `df`.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.apply()` returns a pd.Series object (a new column). Assuming that you want to replace the existing column, you can write `df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: edit(x))`

Comment: using df_train in place of df wont throw a 'Type Error'

Comment: nice catch haha, but it was just my mistake while posting. The actual code has the correct df name. and gave me the type error

Comment: @YunTaeHwang What's the exact error message?

Comment: Hi @YunTaeHwang. Please allow me to explain my edit, there are two reasons behind it. Firstly, on Stack Overflow there is an expectation of technical writing - we trim out chat, conversation, niceties and politenesses, so that what is left is just technical information. Think of the result like an encyclopaedia or a reference manual - no hellos, no great displays of gratitude, no life stories, no tales of woe and suffering. This makes material nice and easy to read for readers now, and in the future.

Comment: The second reason is that some niceties we see here are understood not merely as polite, but as begging - the intent behind them is that the question author wishes to convey their great distress to readers in order to coerce them into helping. In other words, it is implied that a volunteer who fails to help is beyond the pale, because they have left a fellow coder in a state of despair. This is not a reasonable approach when addressing volunteers.

Comment: So, please, [keep your posts succinct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions), and express your gratitude in upvotes and accept votes. I am happy to discuss further if needs be - open a chat with me and I can expand further on this theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have made minor mistake ! dataframe name is wrong while applying !!!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'text':["I love a dog", "He is smart", "I hate this"]})

def edit(input_text):
    output = input_text[:4]
    return output

df['text'].apply(lambda x: edit(x))
```

Comment: nice catch haha, but it was just my mistake while posting. The actual code has the correct df name. and gave me the type error

Comment: using df_train in place of df wont throw a 'Type Error', but a 'Name Error' instead. I think it was a typo while posting